How to setup only-office in nextcloud using nextcloud interface?
I installed Nextcloud from a ZIP file on my own server, but now I want to open Word files. I found a solution that involves using OnlyOffice. I downloaded OnlyOffice from the Nextcloud interface, and now I need to enter the OnlyOffice server address and a secret key. I don't know how to find either of them. Can you help me ?
I tried to enter the address of my own server because Nextcloud created a file named OnlyOffice on my server. However, the error message says it didn't find the path : domaine/healthcheck. When I enter the path to Nextcloud (domaine/nextcloud), the message says: bad healthcheck. I want to know why I am receiving these error messages
Thank you for reading.

If I understand it correctly then nextcloud offers only an integration of OnlyOffice, but not an OnlyOffice itself. You will have to install that separately (as a service in parallel to nextcloud) and then you can integrate it.

I understand, thank you.
